# Magento2 Get all the status of single order update ( Track of order status history ) block in order details page

Tags: magento2, admin-panel, order-status

My requirement is to have a track of order status update ( irrespective of comments update from admin dashboard ) of single order on details page of admin dashboard.
Would like to display as a block at the bottom of the page.
The format would be something like below :

ORDER MOVEMENT STATUS OF ORDER #01156433

Timestamp 1 | Order Status 1

Timestamp 2 | Order Status 2

Kindly guide as to how we can achieve this in Magento2.

Thank You in advance.

Comment: Any comments here?